# MySQL Query can we count rows using php to reduce time of count(*) in a query or there is no difference?

Tags: mysql, php, mysql-workbench, count

Having the following queries, where the first query is returning a field of number of rows found, and the second returns the actual rows:

First Query:

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM individual i WHERE i.hid=:hhid AND i.hihh=:answer
```

Second Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *

FROM 
       individual i
WHERE 
       i.hid=:hhid
AND 
       i.hihh=:answer";

$exec = $conn->prepare($checkHeadOfHH);
$exec->bindValue(':hhid', $hhid);
$exec->bindValue(':answer', $answer);
$count=$exec->rowCount();
```

I want to know if the parser when a query contains `count()`, do `SELECT * FROM..` first then count the rows ? If yes, so basically, is better to use the second approach for better performance and less execution time ?

I am asking this question, because of having huge database and we always run `count(*)` queries to check data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one will be best. The server will only return a number in the first case. In the second it will return a table.

You can get better performance by creating indexes for the columns you are using in the where clause.

**Responses to your replies via comments**

> Creating indexes the way I did in the second query?

No. Creating an index is something you do on MySQL, the database management system. The second query copies a table from MySQL to PHP, and then PHP counts the records. The first query let MySQL do the counting. That is way more efficient.

Look at [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) to see how to create indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Shoveling the rows from MySQL to PHP costs more than letting MySQL do the work.

Adding `INDEX(hid, hihh)` (in either order) would help performance.  Having two one-column indexes is *not* as good:  `INDEX(hid), INDEX(hihh)`.